# What is the best way to create a unique key and persist to encryption?

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption

I'm creating a new ios app that uses encryption. The method I have been using need a unique key to encrypt. Like:

```
- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key;
```

Currently I'm using NSUUID to generate the unique id:

```
[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]
```

And saving the id using the KeychainItemWrapper:

```
[keychainItem setObject:[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString] forKey:(id)kSecAttrService];
```

The unique id is generated in some moment in the first time the user opens the app.

I'm wondering if there is a better way. Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is no guarantee that NSUUID will produce random results. In fact, it's reasonable to think that there may be deterministic elements to something that is supposed to uniquely identify something on a given device. If your requirement is to produce a random key of specified bit length, you'll want to generate that many random bits. Look at [Apple's Randomization Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/RandomizationReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007281)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UUIDs contain portions that are not random. In particular you do not want a string nor a key that is not the exact correct length. Keys should be an array of binary bytes.

Use Common Crypto [SecRandomCopyBytes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/RandomizationReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecRandomCopyBytes) to get a random key.

Further UUIDs are 128-bit values, you may want a longer key such as 256-bits.

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]
```

Here is what Apple describes about it:

[image]

Comment: How is this better than the OP's method?

Comment: As @J. Lopes say it takes some time to get the unique id for first launch, this one should work. [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString] also gives a unique id.

Comment: No he doesn't say that; I believe he's saying it happens when the user runs the app for the first time.

Comment: Yes thats what i mean first time launch of the app only.

Comment: The question is asking if the approach being used is the best approach. Your answer doesn't provide an answer to that question. Your answer simply provides an alternative to using `NSUUID`.

Comment: Yeah I said what @trojanfoe said.

Comment: Anyway: why is your solution better @ArunGupta? Can you explain me that? Thanks.